# Fall/winter gardening tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

Would it be useful to have a fall/winter gardening tag? We've got a handful of questions that this would fit.

If so, what should it be called? [fall-gardening](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fall-gardening) and [winter-gardening](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/winter-gardening) would overlap, and [off-season-gardening](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/off-season-gardening) seems too wordy (and not obvious).

Answer (score 3):

I would prefer bstpierre's suggestion of having [fall-gardening](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fall-gardening), [winter-gardening](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/winter-gardening) in addition to wax eagle's [off-season](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/off-season). That way, a question on planting kale/carrots could be tagged just [fall-gardening](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fall-gardening) (because that's the season for them) and if you're planning on just growing plants off-season (e.g., perennials which would've taken off great if planted in spring, but too bad you forgot and now want to plant them in the fall) you could use both tags.

They shouldn't be synonyms of each other either, because I think they represent different concepts.

Comment: ok, we will just make autumn and fall a syn...:)

Answer (score 2):

How about just [off-season](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/off-season) instead. This would be for anything related to off season gardening and planting. It could also relate to non-growing season lawn maintenance and some other useful things.

Comment: Yes, perhaps with fall-gardening and winter-gardening (or something similar) as synonyms. I'm thinking of people who might start typing "fall" or "winter" (which are obvious choices) in the tags box so they will find those existing tags.

Comment: seems very reasonable.

Comment: @bstpierre, please don't forget some of us use the term "Autumn" instead of "Fall".

Comment: @Mike - don't worry we will give you a synonym too :)

Comment: @Mike - Some of you also sprinkle stray Us in words like color and humor as well, we don't mind ;)

Comment: @bstpierre, that's why we like "Autumn" so much, 2 Us in there makes us feel happy & warm inside ;-)